# How can I refer to a specific tab using JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to add an applet to one of my tabs, but each time I try to add it to a certain tab, it's creating a new tab.

I have already made the tabbed pane using netbeans, added panels to both of the tabs and tried to replace the panel with my applet panel and it's not working correctly. My questions is how can I refer to the "Game" tab and add the applet to that panel?

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/q0lfuz9cxp757n8/Screenshot%202014-07-13%2001.06.42.png

Here's what I'm trying

```
                TabbedPane tabbedPane = new TabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.gameTab.add(gamePanel);
```

And it keeps creating a new tab as seen in the image, but I'm trying to add the gamePanel to the existing "Game" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't want to keep creating a new JTabbedPane. You want to update the existing tabbed pane.

Read the JTabbedPane API. There are several approaches you could use:

1) Use the `remove(...)` method to remove the current tab, then use the add(...) method to add a new tab. The API allows you to add a tab to the end or at a specific index. This is probably the easiest.

2) Use the `getComponentAt(...)` method to get the panel that was added to a specific table. Then you can add any component to this panel, assuming you have a proper layout.

In both cases the question is why isn't the applet added when you initially create the tab?

Comment: The applet is added as expect, but to a totally new tab. If you look at the image it creates a new tab with no name and I want to add the applet to the "Game" tab that already exists. I could create them manually but I'm trying to do it using the Netbeans GUI builder so I can edit them easier, but I can't add the applet to an existing panel.

Comment: `but I can't add the applet to an existing panel.` - why not, its just a panel. If you are using a proper layout manager you can add any component to the panel. I suggest you don't use an IDE to generate the code so you can use/maintain the code easier.

Comment: And so that you can understand what the heck you're doing.

Comment: The purpose of using the builder is so I can avoid creating and positioning the components manually.. All I need to know how to do is refer to the specific tab so I can replace the blank JPanel with my applet's panel

Comment: @Kieran: that may be the purpose, but the unintended side effect is that it shields you from having to learn the library that you're using, and will make it more difficult when you want to create a GUI that veers even a little bit from the most basic GUI.

Comment: `so I can avoid creating and positioning the components manually` - that is why you should be using layout managers. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of components. `All I need to know how to do is refer to the specific tab` you have already been given that answer.